# SOAP request multiple stock prices

Tags: xml, soap, wsdl, soapui

I need to look up a list of stocks from the [GetStockQuote WSDL](http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx) and save all the fields into a database.

Right now I'm just trying to write the SOAP message that will return the results for multiple stocks. With the following code I can look up one stock, but how do I change it to look up multiple stocks? For example, if I wanted IBM, ALJ and AJG? I'm using soapUI to execute the request.

Request:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"  xmlns:web="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <web:GetQuote>
     <web:symbol>'IBM'</web:symbol>
      </web:GetQuote>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Returns:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <GetQuoteResponse xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">
         <GetQuoteResult><![CDATA[<StockQuotes><Stock><Symbol>IBM</Symbol>  <Last>194.1399</Last><Date>6/11/2012</Date><Time>11:08am</Time><Change>-1.0001</Change><Open>196.60</Open><High>196.70</High><Low>194.00</Low><Volume>1033982</Volume><MktCap>223.9B</MktCap><PreviousClose>195.14</PreviousClose><PercentageChange>-0.51%</PercentageChange><AnnRange>157.13 - 210.69</AnnRange><Earns>13.407</Earns><P-E>14.56</P-E><Name>International Bus</Name></Stock></StockQuotes>]]></GetQuoteResult>
      </GetQuoteResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

That particular webservice only has a function call for one Symbol per request as shown in the page you supplied. You will have to make multiple SOAP requests.